# List<t> return type changes to T[] when using a getter in a different project

Tags: c#, generics, setter, getter

Basically I have two projects in Visual Studio 2010. Project 1 contains a getter/setter pair like this:

```
public class MyFirstType
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public List<T> OtherList {set; get; }
    public override String toString() { ... }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<MyFirstType> MyType { get; set; };
    public override String toString() { ... }
}
```

In project2 I try to use this MyClass like this:

```
MyClass mclass = new MyClass();
List<MyFirstType> myTypeList = mclass.MyType;
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyType[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyFirstType>'
```

I just don't understand what happens here. If I use this construct inside of project1 I will get a List.

I am aware that a List is internally represented as T[]. But why is here a change in behaviour of the return type?

Comment: Was it an array in the past? Sounds to me simply like one of the projects hasn't built correctly, or is referencing an old version

Comment: @MarcGravell suggestion is more likely than my answer... Where is that mythical "convert comment into answer" when you need it :)

Comment: `public List<T> OtherList {set; get; }` that shouldn't compile at all; you haven't defined `T` in that context.

Comment: @Servy This line is just to show that there is another generic list used inside of this class. Actually is just another type that I didn't have mentioned.

Comment: As a general observation: when something like WCF site between the two, it is essential to mention that fact.

Comment: Is it in WCF, If so genearate the proxy with `/ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1`. If both the project are different class libraries then you should not get the casting error unless your code is proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Project 1 is WCF service or classes uses through WCF service than by default List was transformed to array. If so you should go to service reference and check appropriate option (convert to List).

Comment: Thanks. Project1 is indeed a WCF service. After configuring it in the right way (Collection Type as List) it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason is you have more than one `MyClass` and code picks up not the one you expect. "F12" (go to definition) usually solves such mysteries quickly.